# Entity Framework 5 turn off auto compilation in RTM?

Tags: entity-framework, entity-framework-5

I see many examples over the internet on how to turn off the automatic compilation with:

```
using (var db = new SampleEntities())
{
    db.ContextOptions.DefaultQueryPlanCaching = false;
}
```

However, I can't see this property anywhere on the db context. It doesn't even have ContextOptions.

There is somewhere on the internet mentioned to cast it to IObjectContextAdapter, there I get ContextOptions, but still not that property

```
((IObjectContextAdapter)db).ObjectContext.ContextOptions.?
```

Note that I'm using the default generation in EF5 which uses DbContext and DbSets.

How do I turn it off? Note also that this is RTM, not beta, or RC of .NET 4.5

Comment: That method *does not* Google at all.

Comment: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.entityclient.entitycommand.enableplancaching.aspx

Comment: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb738562.aspx

Comment: CTP 2011 http://blogs.msdn.com/b/efdesign/archive/2011/06/30/auto-compiled-linq-queries-entity-framework-june-2011-ctp.aspx

Comment: sorry, I'm missing the "Setting" ending as stated in the links above...typo

((IObjectContextAdapter)db).ObjectContext.ContextOptions.DefaultQueryPlanCachingSetting = false;

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would not recommend this as this will most likely produce worse performance than better.  This option is only available at the [ObjectQuery](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb345303.aspx) level not the [ObjectContext](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.objects.objectcontext.aspx) level.

```
var objectContext = ((IObjectContextAdapter)db).ObjectContext;
var objectSet = objectContext.CreateObjectSet<AccountsOnMonth>();
objectSet.EnablePlanCaching = false;
```

[Exerpt](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/data/hh949853.aspx)

> The query plan cache is shared across ObjectContext instances within the same AppDomain. You don't need to hold onto an ObjectContext instance to benefit from query plan caching.

Comment: Found that example already, only was not sure if that is the latest information. 
About performance...I've tried it and on a simple query its faster with turned off autocompilation, while on a more complex query autocompilation turned on gives almost double the faster results.
Which actually makes sense as the autocompilation model has some overhead, so naturally that in simple queries it can be slower than without it.

Thank you for your answer!

Comment: Yes a 1 time query is is faster without it, but the [cache is stored per app-domain](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/data/hh949853.aspx) so until either the Win32 app quits, or the IIS App pool is recycled, it is almost always better to leave it enabled and cached.